# submit button not working in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I did not find any errors in my code below.  While submitting the form, however, nothing is happening.  Specifically, my page is not redirected to other page.  I am testing this code locally using CodeIgniter on WAMP server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Register New</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php $attributes = array('AUTOCOMPLETE' => 'off','method' =>'post');?>
  <?=form_open('welcome/register',$attributes);?>
  <table align="center" border="0">
    <th>
      <td colspan="3" >
        <font color="#0033FF" title="" face="Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="+1">Register  New</font>
      </td>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:14px">
      <?php
          $vmsg=$this->session->userdata('msg');
          if($vmsg)
            echo  $vmsg;
          $this->session->unset_userdata('msg');?><?=validation_errors();
      ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>User Name: </td>
      <td><div align="center" style="font:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  color:#FF0000; font-size:14px;">*</div></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Designation: </td>
      <td><div align="center" style="font:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  color:#FF0000; font-size:14px;">*</div></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="desig" id="desig" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone No.: </td>
      <td><div align="center" style="font:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  color:#FF0000; font-size:14px;">*</div></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ph_no" id="ph_no" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Login ID:</td>
      <td><div align="center" style="font:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FF0000; font-size:14px;">*</div></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="login_id" id="login_id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><div align="center" style="font:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FF0000; font-size:14px;">*</div></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Retype Password:</td>
      <td><div align="center" style="font:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  color:#FF0000; font-size:14px;">*</div></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="re_pwd" id="re_pwd" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Save" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Note the `form_open` directive within the PHP code.

How can I fix the form submission process?

Comment: what does method `form_open` looks like?

Comment: You could cut the html bloat by a huge fraction by not using inline styles and using a css class instead.

Comment: If you need help with just the form, show the rendered HTML rather than the php code, I.e. the page source in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have an opening `<form method="">` to close your `</form>`

Add this in above your actual form. Example:

```
<form method="POST"> 

<tr><td>User Name: </td>
<td><div align="center" style="font:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  color:#FF0000; font-size:14px;">*</div></td>
```

Comment: I presume the php `form_open()` call just after the <body> tag does that, because there is a `</form>` at the end of the page

Comment: but in codignitor I have done a lot more pages in this same way and got my  results. but the diff is i have done those in my remote server and now in my own laptop using localhost

Answer (score 3):

Well, It seems your form is not even wrapped in a `<form>` tag, there's a start.

Comment: but in codignitor I have done a lot more pages in this same way and got my  results. but the diff is i have done those in my remote server and now in my own laptop using localhost. .here the <?=form_open('welcome/register',$attributes);?> is used instead of <form> tag

Comment: the form open/close creates the form tags.